# Bootstrap 4: get the last card in card column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, masonry

I'm using Bootstrap 4 to build a masonry card deck.
Now I have 3 columns with 3 cards in it.
Is it possible to adress the last card of every column?

I could adress the last card of the deck with the following code:

```
card-columns div.card:last-of-type
```

But is this also possible for every column?

This is the code of the card deck:

```html
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card p-3">
    <blockquote class="card-block card-blockquote">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer>
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-inverse card-primary p-3 text-center">
    <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
      <footer>
        <small>
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img img-fluid" src="..." alt="Card image">
  </div>
  <div class="card p-3 text-right">
    <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer>
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
.card-columns div.card:nth-child(3n)
```

this gets the last card of every column

Comment: Please note that this is only a solution for THIS specific situation. If - in the future - the amount of columns will change, then this won't work anymore.

Comment: Is it possible to post some of your rendered HTML code/structure? That way it would be easier for us to help you with finding a dynamic solution to the problem. If you would be interested of course.

Comment: see above in my question

Answer (score 1):

This would be a dynamic solution to the problem, with the given HTML structure.

```css
.card-columns div.card p:last-child {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
    <p>The first paragraph of div 1.</p>
    <p>The second paragraph of div 1.</p>
    <p>The third paragraph of div 1.</p>
    <p>The fourth paragraph of div 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>The first paragraph of div 2.</p>
    <p>The second paragraph of div 2.</p>
    <p>The third paragraph of div 2.</p>
    <p>The fourth paragraph of div 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need it for every card, see code above. not the <p>-tags inside a card.